# How to install GUI desktop on a server?

Tags: system-installation, package-management

After installing Ubuntu server how do I install the desktop environment?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Depending on which desktop you wish to install, you install the the meta-package that installs all the necessary packages. You can use `apt-get` or `aptitude` to do this.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

installs the Unity desktop

```
sudo aptitude install kubuntu-desktop
```

would install the KDE desktop

Other desktop meta-packages are `xubuntu-desktop`, `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`, `lubuntu-desktop`, and `edubuntu-desktop` .

Comment: For onlookers, here's additional info I found useful that's on the same wavelength as the answer - http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-gui-in-ubuntu-server.html

Comment: typically you want the answer below that doesn't install recommended packages

Answer (score 42):

If you wan to install a graphical desktop manager without some of the desktop addons like Evolution and OpenOffice, but continue to use the server flavor kernel use the following command

```
sudo aptitude install --without-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: dam... started the install from the answer and scrolled down to this. :(

Comment: my version of aptitude doesn't have that option.  It does have --without-recommends

Comment: @JHowIX try using apt-get instead, that one worked for me.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop` or  
`sudo aptitude install --without-recommends ubuntu-desktop`

Answer (score 11):

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score 9):

If you just need to run virtual GUI (GUI exsists but you dont need to see it) on the computer for testing or other purposes.

`sudo apt-get install xvnc4viewer`

Is a setup I have.

:)

Comment: So, the server isn't running the desktop, but you can still VNC from a client machine and get a desktop?  That would be perfect for my needs (dunno about the OP).

Comment: yeah you see a graphical shell.

Answer (score 7):

From Ubuntu 20.04, we could use `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop-minimal` to **minimal install** `ubuntu-desktop`, it removes around 80 packages (and related cruft) from the default install, including Thunderbird, LibreOffice and so on.

The command could replace the old command `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop` or `sudo aptitude install --without-recommends ubuntu-desktop`.