# Why is the networking options disabled on Ubuntu 20.04 Login sceen

Tags: 20.04, gnome

Good Day,

Wonder if anyone knows why the networking applet on Ubuntu 20.04 login gdm is disabled ?

I have been searching for a way to to make it enabled like Fedora 34 - but for some reason the information is sparse on the topic, unless i am searching for the wrong keywords.

My assumption is that some policy is enabled but not sure where to look - any advice would be grateful

[image]

Comment: Do you need a particular connection active without a user logging in? You should be able to configure network manager to automatically connect. Or do you specifically want connection options at login screen? Edit - this may be helpful? https://askubuntu.com/questions/16376/connect-to-network-before-user-login

Comment: So the default networking is not available as you can see from the screenshot. We want to setup a universal VPN connection that users can click to connect BEFORE login. Because we can not save the username password we can not auto dial it. so the user needs to click VPN - type a username and password which then connects

Comment: There is a LDAP server that is not public so the users needs to be able to VPN before typing a username and password - if that makes sense. We did specify that the VPN connection is available to all users - but still shows greyed out. We also tested this on Fedora 34 as a POC and that login screen does allow you to connect. Which leads me to believe there is some policy that controls it - but no idea how to change it