# How to auto-boot into text mode?

Tags: 10.10, boot, command-line, gdm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable X at boot time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-to-disable-x-at-boot-time)

How to configure my Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop (Maverick) to start in a Terminal like mode? I don't want any graphics.

I can't get rid of GDM. How should I disable only graphical interface of my Ubuntu? I want it to start only in text mode, but I want that everything else would start-up.

I can't use recovery mode, because I want that it would run in text mode all the time even after restarts.

Comment: I don't understand, do you want to run a server?

Comment: I can't understand the "I can't get rid of GDM". Removing GDM seems to be what you are looking for.