# How to always boot into a CLI environment?

Tags: server, grub2, xubuntu, console, headless

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable X at boot time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-to-disable-x-at-boot-time)

The title says it all really.

I've got Xubuntu 11.04 working as a file server which I SSH into. 90% of the time it's headless and therefore requires no GUI. I don't want to install just a bare server however because there are times when I want the graphical environment.

How do I best do this? I've already set `GRUB_DEFAULT=1` in /etc/default/grub but this is doesn't do what I want as I then drop into an ncurses style menu prior to getting a prompt.

I want a normal console.

Answer (score 0):

In the file /etc/default/grub make sure that the line starting with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=
contains the word "text", e.g. GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nosplash text". Then run update-grub.
When you reboot, you should go to a login prompt. I've had my home server set up this way for a couple of years.

P.S. Have you looked at Webmin to administer your server? It's great.

Comment: OK, I'll give that a try, cheers. It's headless now so I'll hook it up tonight and report back. Haven't tried Webmin. Will do.

Comment: This hasn't worked for me unfortunately. When you say "text" do you mean "text" or "nosplash text"? Anyway, I've hosed the system (separate issue, don't worry) so I'll get back to you on this one. Thanks again.

Comment: Did you run sudo update-grub ?

Comment: @NRoach44: Yeh, I did.

Comment: Note that Zentyal is preferred over Webmin. Also 'nosplash' does *nothing* since sometime before 10.04 (it controlled usplash, which was superseded by plymouth)

Comment: okay, "edit" (view) the grub entry for the OS, and check that after the UUID, somewhere around there should be your "text", if it isn't there, you may not have saved the file.