# How do I boot into console mode?

Tags: 11.10, grub2, lightdm, console

In previous versions of Ubuntu I could get the computer to boot into console mode by setting the variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to `"text"` in the file `/etc/default/grub` and run `sudo update-grub`. In Ubuntu 11.10, however, it has no effect - I am still presented with the LightDM login screen. Any clues?