# How do I boot a server without X?

Tags: server, configuration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I boot into console mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70188/how-do-i-boot-into-console-mode)

I'm looking for a solution, to start my server only with a shell. I don't need the unity windowmanager because i want to save ressources. On this server runs a webserver with my webservices in semi-production. So for default it is enough to start in a bash and access the server vie putty. no windowmanager is needed.

Please assist, how to configure the system to start only in shell by default?

Answer (score 2):

what version of ubuntu did you install ? desktop is the one version of ubuntu which support unity as desktop manager , because *ubuntu server edition* start with a shell without GUI optimize for this case.

**How to get it ?**

[Ubuntu server Edition](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/download)

From Ubuntu Docs (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/)

**What's the difference between desktop and server?**

> The first difference is in the CD contents. The "Server" CD avoids
>   including what Ubuntu considers desktop packages (*packages like X*)
>   but includes server related packages (Apache2, Bind9 and so on). Using
>   a Desktop CD with a minimal installation and installing, for example,
>   apache2 from the network, one can obtain the exact same result that
>   can be obtained by inserting the Server CD and installing apache2 from
>   the cd-rom.
>
> The Ubuntu Server Edition installation process is slightly different
>   then the Desktop Edition. Since by default Ubuntu Server doesn't have
>   a GUI the process is menu driven, very similar to the Alternate CD
>   installation process. Ubuntu server install by default a server
>   optimized kernel. Ubuntu Desktop will receive a 3 years support,
>   Ubuntu Server will be supported for 5 years.

- [How to check if ubuntu desktop or server is installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12562/how-to-check-if-ubuntu-desktop-or-server-is-installed) (see Paweł Karpiński answer)

**How to Remote Administration (like putty, remmina etc...)?**

*ubuntu server recommend  this two package :*

- Openssh server
- Puppet

[Chapter 5. Remote Administration](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/serverguide/C/remote-administration.html)

P.S: If you have got a desktop installation you can see this post, the first option doesn't work because there is a bug:

[How do I boot into console mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70188/how-do-i-boot-into-console-mode)

Comment: okay, i ws sure i installed the server version a couple weeks ago. But the system information says only Ubuntu 11.10. So can i repeat the question, how to start my version in a shell without gui to saving performance?

Comment: I'm not really sure, if installed the server but the download link semms familiar. can you give me a tip, how i can read out the version of my installation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [Ubuntu Server Edition](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/download). If you have a window manager, you definitely haven't installed the Server Edition. In theory, you could uninstall the desktop specific packages and install server edition's specific packages, but I would recommend reinstalling the system with the [Ubuntu Server Edition](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/download) version.