# How to switch from GUI to console mode

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable X at boot time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-to-disable-x-at-boot-time)

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 LiveCd.
How can I switch from GUI mode to console mode?

P.S. I want my system started in console mode by default!

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+f1 through 6

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I want my system launch at startup in console mode by default!

Comment: Uninstall the GUIs.. or use the server version

Comment: It isn't very good idea for me, because I want to switch from Gui mode to console mode. But I don't want to install/uninstall Gui every time.

Comment: askubuntu.com/questions/74645/possible-to-install-ubuntu-desktop-and-then-boot-to-no-gui