# How do I stop or start the desktop from loading on bootup?

Tags: 11.10, boot, lightdm

I occasionally want to use my Ubuntu machine as a desktop but mostly 
as a headless file server.  Before I upgraded to Oneiric, I 
used rcconf services to disable or enable the desktop.  In Oneiric I 
don't see GDM; so can't uncheck it.  LightDM appears but isn't checked.
I don't see anything else that looks like a desktop.

So, how can I disable, an occasionally enable, the Oneiric desktop?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-to-disable-x-at-boot-time Might help one part of that.