# Ubuntu startup run level

Tags: runlevel

How do I make Ubuntu 12.04 to start at a runlevel other than default 2.although I could change run level after starting from terminal it does not remain when I restart

Comment: This already seems to answer your question http://askubuntu.com/questions/228402/boot-to-runlevel-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give the kernel your desired run-level on boot by  pressing `C` with your boot-entry selected and add `init=<your-runlevel-number>` to the kernel parameter passed on boot and press `F10` to boot with that edited line once.

Or you can edit your `grub.cfg` to edit the parameters permanent (not recommended for Ubuntu and other distributions that check for change of important configuration files).
@videonauth suggest in chat and is right about that you have to update the `/etc/default/grub` and the files in `/etc/grub.d/` instead followed by a `sudo update-grub` to update your installation properly.

Comment: BTW what is boot entry. is it entry on grub menu

Comment: yup, it is the entry on the grub menu.

Comment: Init statement was not found however initrd was.so should I use inird