# Add new entry in Grub2 for text mode on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, text-mode

It is for a while I am trying to find a way to add another entry to grub2 which takes me to text mode.

I have already seen lots of posts but either they are for make a permanent change (which makes grub always take me to text mode) or they are too old and not working on newer version (like [this one](http://ubuntuguide.net/add-a-grub2-entry-for-ubuntu-booting-into-consolecommand-line))

I hope I was able to make it clear what I am looking for. I want to keep the current entry for booting into graphical mode but also I want to have an entry for booting into text mode.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You should boot to run level 3. It has been already described here: [Boot to Runlevel 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228402/boot-to-runlevel-3)

Comment: Though it was for Ubuntu 12.04, but it seems it is working fine on 16.04 too. Can you include detail (including the 16.04 grub menu) so this answer can be useful?

Comment: What detail do you need. Everything should be explained in linked article.

Comment: First of all, sharing link is not the proper way or answering a question. Link can be shared as comment. Secondly, i went through it but I could solve the problem a bit differently since his instruction for grub alteration didn't work for me. Perhaps I will come with my workflow. Yet, thank you I much for sharing the link and giving me the clue