# Enable/Disable Ubuntu Desktop environment on ubuntu-12.04.1-server-i386

Tags: server, desktop-environments, services

I have installed **ubuntu-12.04.1-server-i386** and on top of that i have installed ***Ubuntu desktop environment*** so that i can maintain server easily.

Hear I totally understand that installing Desktop environment will affect my server efficiency but its quit easy to maintain server with GUI so I am wondering that is there any workaround to enable or disable ***Ubuntu Desktop Environment*** whenever we need it like we do in Windows for services ?
I searched and reffed many sites but did not found anything related to this.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor English.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a specific instance of a generic question, "how do I prevent an upstart service from running at boot".

You can use an override:

> sudo echo "manual" >> /etc/init/lightdm.override

To start lightdm on command:

> sudo start lightdm

To restore your system so that lightdm is always started on boot:

> sudo rm /etc/init/lightdm.override

For more information, the upstart cookbook is your friend:

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/

SRC : [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79651/how-do-i-stop-or-start-the-desktop-from-loading-on-bootup)

Comment: And how do I shut down the GUI again?

Comment: sudo service lightdm stop

Comment: Doesn't `sudo` refer to `echo`? Your first `sudo echo "manual" >> ...` has no permission to write to `/etc/init/`.

Comment: I had that problem as well. >> is not run as root. sudo -i first is a good work around.

Comment: It's back to gdm so you should create /etc/init/gdm.override with the contents as above, these days (2016)

Comment: A better one-liner is `sudo tee /etc/init/lightdm.override <<< manual`. This has the adequate privileges to write the file.

Answer (score 4):

Try to disable GUI, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f gdm remove
```

When you restart your computer, you’ll get text-mode login.  To run GUI again:

```
startx
```

To enable GUI again:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f gdm defaults
```

<sup>Source:[HTG](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/prevent-xorg-from-starting-in-ubuntu/)</sup>

Comment: I execute command "sudo update-rc.d -f gdm remove" nothing happens! then i tried "sudo service lightdm stop" but it stops at checking battery stste and "sudo service gdm stop" is unrecognized service

Comment: I installed 12.04 server yesterday, and followed the steps, and it worked.  Did exactly as the source said.  Let me know.

Comment: i have have added image in the question. I guess the command is not executing properly

Comment: "sudo echo "manual" >> /etc/init/lightdm.override" worked for me

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work for me.  see [image](http://ubuntuone.com/0P1P6q6HoA3aKVAYxuDTDi)

Comment: may be because lightdm is not installed in your system

Comment: It seems you have to use the /etc/init.d/something.override technique these days

Answer (score 0):

Another way to avoid the permissions issue, is to use 'tee'. Like so:

```
echo "manual" | sudo tee /etc/init/lightdm.override
```