# How do I boot into true text mode?

Tags: boot, text, text-mode

I've found ways to disable `gdm` or `lightdm` or whatever 11.10 uses, but I can't find a way to get a true text-mode boot. I want to see all the kernel messages fly by as it boots, not a stupid purple screen.

I got the desktop manager turned off finally, but now I get a purple screen for a while, then it switches to TTY1. After that happens, I get about half a screen of kernel messages (the end of the boot sequence; stuff about running init scripts etc.) and the login prompt. I did this by changing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` to `text` in `/etc/defaults/grub`.

Really my main question is, what is putting that dumb purple screen up at boot, and how do I disable it!?

Comment: press up button while booting.

Comment: Check out this [post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1975118&page=2&p=12568835#post12568835) for a how-to on hi-res text boot with plymouth.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable X at boot time so that the system boots in text mode?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-do-i-disable-x-at-boot-time-so-that-the-system-boots-in-text-mode)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Edit in `/etc/default/grub`

```
# Stops the ubuntu purple screen
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only) 
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

Then run a `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Didn't see the GRUB_TERMINAL value. Thanks a lot. This worked. I only changed the values I had seen people mention online. I never feel comfortable editing boot loader configuration scripts. I'm always afraid that I will have to use my rescue flash drive :P

Comment: `apt-get purge plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text` - This clears a lot of crud after you do the above

Comment: @IanMacintosh, what crud does it clear? On my machine it says it's going to free 84kB of disk space. Does it remove something else as well?

Comment: @IanMacintosh, so I tried this. The command spent quite a while on `update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-26-generic`. Afterwards I rebooted and compared the output of bootchart. The time to boot went up by around two seconds. The delay appears to have been caused by `busybox`. After reinstalled `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text` boot time dropped back. I can't explain why this is, but it's what I observed.

Comment: Re "What is putting that dumb purple screen up at boot" - It's the plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text. So purging it is the quick and simple way of getting rid of that.

Comment: Boot speed will be negatively affected if you write a lot of text to the screen, particularly in a graphical mode with slow scrolling. The question isn't about trying to boot 5 seconds faster. You could try a new question and see how that pans out.

Comment: how do I change the size of the text (resolution of the console)? I have a laptop that shows really small text and another one that shows really big text on the screen. But I can't find where to configure this size. I want both to have high resolution (to show small text)

Answer (score 5):

To ensure 'that dumb purple screen' never shows up again after boot, do the following on the `/etc/default/grub` file:

- `sudo vi /etc/default/grub`
- Press <kbd>i</kbd> to enter into vi edit mode.
- Uncomment the line which reads `#GRUB_TERMINAL=console` by removing the leading `#`
- Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit vi edit mode.
- Type <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> to save the change made to the `/etc/default/grub` file and exit vi
- Update `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to have your change apply by running `sudo update-grub`

  If your computer uses systemd, you must tell systemd to skip the default login GUI thus:
- `sudo systemctl enable multi-user.target --force`
- `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target`
- Reboot your computer: `sudo reboot`

Now, 'that dumb purple screen' will never show up again.

Remember, you must update `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to have your changes apply.

Answer (score 1):

From the Grub boot menu editor (i.e. the menu that shows up while your machine is booting),  you can try to comment the "load_video" line.

Comment: I found that I had to do this ** worked when I also delete "quiet splash"

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to prevent the kernel from changing video modes which can be problematic, especially if you cannot see the login prompt or it is partially off the screen. Add the setting GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset" to /etc/default/grub:

```
#GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
#GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
#for text mode boot up... and also uncomment the "console" terminal
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text"
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```