# Boot in text mode break X

Tags: boot, grub2, lightdm

this is my first question and i hope not be breaking any rules.

I was trying to boot at text mode and followed these articles
[How do I boot into true text mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92276/how-do-i-boot-into-true-text-mode)

[Disable automatic unity launching?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131497/disable-automatic-unity-launching?lq=1)

[How do I disable X at boot time so that the system boots in text mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-do-i-disable-x-at-boot-time-so-that-the-system-boots-in-text-mode)

all saying to edit grub file, I did and it works BUT when use "startx" to go to graphic mode everything is broken... the desktop only shows few icons... i cant click nothing, there isn`t menu bar, clock, nothing... the only option is "control + alt + T" to open a shell and do something...

if i type `service lightdm start` an error message is returned

if i type `service lightdm stop [or] force-reload` an error says there isnt lightdm process

if i type `startx` nothing changes

im using ubuntu 14.04.2  64bits

So my question is:

- Are there any way off do the oposite? boot at graphic mode and type a command to disable it and go to text?
- or, anyone knows what can be wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to boot into text mode but nonetheless try to use X afterall ?

Comment: and if you go back to booting with graphics enabled it all works normally ? I'd guess some of the init scripts need to be started in addition to lightdm, but it's only a guess