# upgrade to 14.04 added lightdm to server edition

Tags: server, upgrade, lightdm, gdm

The update from 13.10 to 14.04 using *do-release-upgrade* seems to have added lightdm to my computer.  On top of that, lightdm wasn’t even set up properly, nor do I want it set up.  I prefer not to use graphical login, and to start with server edition and install only things I want on my desktop, just out of preference.

I got to a console and tried apt-get removing lightdm, which made gdm install.  Attempting to remove gdm tries to make kdm install and nvidia-prime remove.  How do I get things back to the way they were before?  I’ve upgraded three times before this without problem.

Comment: [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/196603/how-to-remove-the-graphical-user-interface) you'll find information on both disabling and removing the GUI.

Comment: I don’t have _ubuntu-desktop_ installed.  I have been using MATE as my window manager but I had no login manager until this upgrade.  I only want to remove the login manager, and I want to know why it gave me one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking common important reverse dependencies (dependents) of lightdm, gdm &  kdm, using:

```
apt-cache -i rdepends lightdm | tail -n +3 | sort
apt-cache -i rdepends gdm | tail -n +3 | sort
apt-cache -i rdepends kdm | tail -n +3 | sort
```

It seems the common one is `nvidia-prime`.

```
$ apt-cache depends nvidia-prime
nvidia-prime
 |Depends: lightdm
 |Depends: gdm
  Depends: kdm
  Depends: upstart
    upstart:i386
  Depends: bbswitch-dkms
  Depends: pciutils
    pciutils:i386
  Depends: lsb-release
 |Depends: sysv-rc
  Depends: <file-rc>
  Conflicts: <hybrid-graphics>
  Conflicts: <hybrid-graphics:i386>
  Breaks: ubuntu-drivers-common
  Breaks: ubuntu-drivers-common:i386
  Replaces: <hybrid-graphics>
    nvidia-prime
  Replaces: <hybrid-graphics:i386>
    nvidia-prime:i386
  Conflicts: nvidia-prime:i386
```

`nvidia-prime` need at least one of lightdm, gdm or kdm. See [How do I boot into true text mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92276/how-do-i-boot-into-true-text-mode) to boot without GUI. Also you may disable lightdm/gdm/kdm services, but not sure if nvidia-prime tools will work, try it.