# I can not boot directly into Text Mode in 14.10

Tags: boot, command-line, grub2, 14.10

I want my Ubuntu 14.10 system to boot directly into command line, so I changed the grub file in (/etc/default/grub) like this :

```
(#)GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet”

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”text”

GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

But the only think that has changed is *I don't have the purple color anymore on the start* :p .

Comment: What is `(#)` supposed to do? To comment the line just place `#` before any other character. Did you followed [this steps](http://askubuntu.com/a/92279/62483)?

Comment: Yeah it's just # I put () to not influence the text, of course as you can see. (update-grub) also ...

Answer (score -1):

I did this,

```
sudo apt-get install upstart

sudo reboot
```

Then I booted into Text Mode.

I found the information here:-

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers