# How do I boot into the console and then launch the Ubuntu desktop from it?

Tags: unity, boot, gnome, command-line, login

At the Ubuntu login page I have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to be able to login as an user using the command line.

But how do I get to the command line first and then start the Ubuntu desktop from it?

Comment: For Ubuntu 15 and above: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-do-i-disable-x-at-boot-time-so-that-the-system-boots-in-text-mode

Answer (score 47, accepted):

#### To *return* to the login screen

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to return to the login screen. You can exit your terminal session on tty1 by typing `exit` before you do that.

Doing `startx -- :1` will start **another** X session under terminal tty1, logging you in directly (use :2, etc. for even more displays). *Note that logging into multiple sessions as the* **same user** *is not recommended* and could lead to system instability.

---

To **skip the login screen** completely, boot into the console and then start the GUI, you must modify GRUB:

- `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
- Change line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>, press <kbd>Y</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save and exit.
- `sudo update-grub`
- Reboot and you should come up directly in tty1 -- no need to press Ctrl-Alt-F1.
- Login, and then `startx` to boot into the default desktop, or

  - `unity` for Unity
  - `unity-2d-shell` for Unity 2D
  - `gnome-shell` for Gnome
  - `sudo service lightdm start` to get the login screen (if you fix it :)

Comment: But I don't want to return to the login screen. The reason is that I can't login at the login screen because the wrong keyboard layout is available. To my idea is: login at the command line and load the ubuntu desktop (or whatever it's called).

Comment: @doYourBit please see extensive edit in the answer

Comment: @izs: How can you start another x session by simply typing startx.  The default display, :0, is already being used, so you would need to specify a different display to use, wouldn't you?  I remember doing it once in the past as an experiment, but it wasn't that simple at the time.  I just tried it, and it didn't work for me.

Comment: @MartyFried : you're absolutely correct, thanks for reminding me. You'd need to do `start -- :DISPLAY` to be successful. I edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: You'll need to wait a bit after seeing the cursor at the top left of the screen until the login appears; or at least I did. I had - out of curiosity I logged out and into a cairo-dock session which left my laptop in an unusable state until I read these instructions.

Comment: @izx Weird, because my startx script has a while loop that increments `$DISPLAY` until it can't find a corresponding `.Xn-lock` file.

Answer (score 13):

To skip the login GUI without using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, simply do the following:

- `sudo vi /etc/default/grub`
- Press <kbd>i</kbd> to enter into vi edit mode.
- Change the line that reads `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"`
- Uncomment the line which reads `#GRUB_TERMINAL=console` by removing the leading `#`
- Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit vi edit mode.
- Type <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> to save the change made to the `/etc/default/grub` file and exit vi.
- Update `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to have your change apply by running `sudo update-grub`

  If your computer uses systemd, you must tell systemd to skip the default login GUI thus:

  ```
  sudo systemctl enable multi-user.target --force
  sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
  ```
- Reboot your computer: `sudo reboot`

Now, the login GUI will never show up.

Once you're in the terminal, run `sudo systemctl start lightdm` to start the default desktop.

Comment: This works perfectly!  The only issue I am seeing is the 'startx' command runs a unity that has an "X" instead of a mouse pointer and no desktop, menu or other icons.  Will post a separate question for that.

Comment: @DaveCollins, thanks for the pointer. I have made a change to the command causing the issue you observed.

Comment: I was missing the `sudo systemctl enable multi-user.target --force
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target` part. Hope this help others like me.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to load a new desktop from the terminal, type one of this things:

- If using **Unity**, type `unity`.
- If using **Unity 2D**, type `unity-2d-shell`.
- If using **GNOME**, type `gnome-shell`.

Or just type `startx` if you want to load the default desktop environment :P

Answer (score 6):

**Temporary single boot to text mode**

Another option to avoid the graphics mode at boot without completely altering your grub configuration is to press 'e' at the grub menu .
This will show you the commands that grub will use to boot and allow you to change them for just this one boot.
find the line that starts like:

```
linux  /boot/vmlinuz-{your current kernel version and root=UUID=some big long id} ro quite splash
```

In 14.04 that line will probably end with "quite splash" but it may end with "nomode"
Whatever it ends with, change it to "text" to tell Linux that you want to boot in text mode.

Then press F10 to boot with the new temporary settings.

**Add text mode menu option to grub**

If you wish to add an item in the grub menu you can follow the instructions in

[Add console/text booting mode to grub menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158551/add-console-text-booting-mode-to-grub-menu)