# Add console/text booting mode to grub menu

Tags: grub2, text-mode

I want to have text booting mode option on grub menu screen. How do I create this menu entry?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my research, there are two ways to do this:

## Method 1

Hack `10_linux` script in `/etc/grub.d/` and insert generation codes for text booting menuentry

**Advantages:**

- Generates text booting menuentry for all installed kernel versions
- Takes care of new or redundant menuentries when you install/purge
  kernels

**Downsides:**

- Requires deep understanding of shell scripting
- The script source file may vary from one grub version to another
- Edits need to be redone if grub package updates overwrite the modified script

## Method 2

Use designated script for adding custom grub menuentry in `/etc/grub.d`

**Advantages:**

- Easiest and least complicated
- No chance of being overwritten so you do it only once

**Downsides:**

- Only if you want each of your installed kernel versions to have text
  booting menuentry:

  - Lots of work and harder to maintain
  - Leaving behind redundant menuentries when you purge old kernel versions

---

In this short step, I'm going with `method #2` since it's the easiest to explain here and we'll be creating text booting menuentry only for the latest kernel image that you use.

1. The first thing that you need is the already generated menuentry for
   your latest kernel. We are going to copy and use it as basis for our
   custom menuentry, with a little alteration. For that, you need to
   look in your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file. Locate the first menuentry
   stanza that points to the latest kernel on your Ubuntu. If you're
   dual booting with other linux distros, pay extra attention so you
   wouldn't mix it up with their menuentries.
2. Once you found it, copy the entire menuentry stanza and paste it
   into `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file. It may look like one below. Let's
   use this as example:

   ```
   menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-a4e6d610-122e-42e2-8497-39eae02816e8' {
     recordfail
     load_video
     gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
     insmod gzio
     insmod part_gpt
     insmod ext2
     set root='hd0,gpt2'
     if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
       search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  a4e6d610-122e-42e2-8497-39eae02816e8
     else
       search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a4e6d610-122e-42e2-8497-39eae02816e8
     fi
     linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-31-generic root=UUID=a4e6d610-122e-42e2-8497-39eae02816e8 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
     initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-31-generic
   }
   ```
3. Now here's few things that you need to edit in this stanza before you can save the file:

   - The menuentry title. Change 'Ubuntu' in `menuentry` line to 'Ubuntu (text mode)'
   - Path to vmlinuz file in `linux` line. Substitute `/boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-31-generic` with `/vmlinuz`
     grub boot parameter at the end of `linux` line. Substitute `quiet splash` with `text`
   - Path to initrd image in `initrd` line. Substitute `/boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-31-generic` with `/initrd.img`
4. Reason why we do the substitutions in both `vmlinuz` and `initrd` lines is to take advantages of the symlinks placed in / which points to their latest version in `/boot` dir so that our custom menuentry can always point to the most recent kernel and won't need to be changed if a new kernel is introduced.
5. That's it. Execute `sudo update-grub` to generate the custom menu and you're done.

Comment: I tried this with Bonic Beaver (Lubuntu) and I still ended up entering graphics mode. The latest method is shown in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029350/348964) to [Add GRUB menu item to boot into terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/1029339/348964)

Answer (score 1):

See:

[The Grub 2 Guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275)

If I have some time, I will try to document how ...