# Login to GUI through Command line

Tags: login, login-screen, auto-login

I want to login to Ubuntu through command line which will then redirect me to GUI, is there any way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I boot into the console and then launch the Ubuntu desktop from it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148717/how-do-i-boot-into-the-console-and-then-launch-the-ubuntu-desktop-from-it)

Answer (score 0):

To boot straight to the command line you need to modify GRUB.

1. Edit grub config file `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
2. Change the option `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to read `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"`
3. Save the file and exit CTRL+X, press Y and then ENTER
4. Type `sudo update-grub` from the terminal to update the GRUB bootloader with your new configuration.
5. Reboot and you should be presented with a terminal instead of X.
6. Type startx to load the default shell.