# startx not starting applications in fullscreen

Tags: unity, 16.04, xorg, display-resolution, fullscreen

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu, I wanted my system to boot to a console (wanted to boot to gnome-terminal but got solution for booting to tty) and no GUI such that whenever I wanted GUI I could start in on demand, so I referred to this [askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148717/how-do-i-boot-into-the-console-and-then-launch-the-ubuntu-desktop-from-it) and now I can boot to tty but now when I start applications with `startx` (ex: `startx firefox`) it opens them but not using the full resolution of my screen that is there is background(black or sometimes colored) that can be seen around the applications.
I tried to change the contents to **xinitrc** file and I tried this in that file: `-geometry 1366x768` but it didn't work and I also tried to give 1366 and 768 as parameters along with `startx` command but that also didn't work. The dropdowns in Firefox (like Bookmarks Dropdown) are also not working when starting firefox with `startx`.

Here's how it looks right now with the background showing to the right and bottom of the window

[image: Here is how it looks right now]

So now I want `startx` to start applications in fullscreen, using my full resolution (the right and bottom background shouldn't be viewed). Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for firefox i.e. i was able to open firefox in fullscreen by using `firefox -width 1366 -height 768` on terminal for opening firefox and then this was set as the default resolution for firefox automatically. And as far the side issue of opening terminal on startup is concerned, still using tty when system starts but now I edited the ~/.xinitrc file such that whenever I run startx from tty, gnome-terminal opens in a particular resolution and at particular location on the screen.Here is my ~/.xinitrc file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
gnome-terminal --geometry=115x24+115+115 &
#exec gnome-session
. /etc/X11/Xsession
```