# Boot first to terminal can't subsequently load graphical unity in 14.04

Tags: boot, command-line, unity, xorg, window-manager

I followed the advice [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/148723/29907) on how to boot to tty1 rather than straight to graphical (that is, I followed the answer's instructions on how to default to the terminal you get when you hit Ctrl-Alt-F1).

However, sometimes I still later want to start a graphical session (that is, the thing you get when you Ctrl-Alt-F7).

I try typing `startx` or `unity`.  However, though `startx` does load a graphical session, it does not load the full desktop environment.  I notice for example I don't have any menu bars, or ability to move to multiple desktops.  This suggests to me there is some other service (window manager maybe?) that is not appropriately starting under `startx`.

How can I launch a true x session subsequent to beginning in

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
```

mode?

Answer (score 1):

In running `startx` you have to specifically setup the desktop environment that you are running.  The defaults will not be the `lightdm` environment.

To have the normal **Ubuntu/Unity** environment you're familiar with you have to run the `lightdm` session.  You can do this by running:

```
$ sudo systemctl start lightdm
```