# Unity X Server not active without physical login

Tags: 16.04, unity, login

I'm using my `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` with `Unity 7.4.5` as a remote server as well as a desktop computer. Unfortunately, when I reboot Ubuntu, I can't get X server benchmarks to run without physically going to my display and logging in directly.

Before I do this physical screen login, I see:

```
t@t:~$ DISPLAY=:0 glmark2-es2
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
```

After I physically login, I see

```
t@t:~$ DISPLAY=:0 glmark2-es2
=======================================================
    glmark2 2014.03+git20150611.fa71af2d
=======================================================
```

And the program runs successfully.

Is there some command I can run remotely to somehow initialize / setup the X server on `:0`? A related question (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199891/invalid-mit-magic-cookie-1-key-when-trying-to-run-program-remotely) doesn't seem to solve the problem.

EDIT: I tried running `startx -- :500` and then `DISPLAY=:500 glmark2-es2` to try to bypass this problem altogether. However, I get

```
test@test:~$ DISPLAY=:500 glmark2-es2
Error: main: Could not initialize canvas
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I boot into the console and then launch the Ubuntu desktop from it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148717/how-do-i-boot-into-the-console-and-then-launch-the-ubuntu-desktop-from-it)

Comment: Not really. The shells I'm showing in this question are all from an ssh client on a remote computer, they're not shells on the local computer. I don't want to skip the login screen on my desktop, I just want to run X server diagnostics remotely without having to go home and login physically to do so. I'm want to find if there is something I can run in the shell remotely to initialize the X server appropriately.

Comment: You either have to log in and leave it logged in or start x from ssh

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: Now you changed the question from how to start an x session. To how to connect to it via ssh