# Booting Ubuntu into the Command Line?

Tags: command-line, tty, init, runlevel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable X at boot time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-to-disable-x-at-boot-time)

How do I boot Ubuntu by default into the CLI using a multiuser runlevel? I wish to still maintain my graphical desktop manager (GDM or whatever replaced it) since I do use that to switch between Unity and Awesome WM. I do however wish to boot by default into a CLI login shell. I could then `startx` to start my GUI if I need it. I am aware that `Ctrl-Alt-(F1-6)` will open a separate tty instance with a login shell but it seems wasteful to have a GUI running even if asleep if I am working purely from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `text` as a kernel boot parameter.

Explained in detail in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/79682/88802) to a possible duplicate question *"How to disable X at boot time?"*.

Comment: Not sure this is a duplicate. How to disable X at boot time?" seems to be talking about disabling it once. This seems to be asking how to have it always disabled. That said if you use this options remember to update grub.

Comment: To make is persistent is quite straightforward. Just make your bootloader (Grub probably) use this parameter by default. And hey, it's *in* the answer already! `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"`

Answer (score -1):

[This Document Should help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpstartHowto)

Basically you edit /etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf and add/change

> env DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL=2

Comment: Make sure the read the document, there are a couple of ways.

Comment: Runlevel 2 isn't without X on my machine. It has been with many other distros.