# How to boot Ubuntu 17.10 into a tty? (without loading gdm)

Tags: grub2, 17.10, display-manager

Following the advice  from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225735/booting-ubuntu-into-the-command-line#225739), I've tried to load Ubuntu without a graphics environment by replacing `quiet splash` in the grub boot script with `text`, and alternately by appending it to the parameters.

This hasn't worked; Ubuntu 17.10 still launched the Gnome Display Manager and shows the login screen. However can I boot Ubuntu 17.10 into a terminal interface? Thank you.

**For future people:** Rinzwind's `systemctl` command works for me, while the similar `systemctl` command from [this previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-do-i-disable-x-at-boot-time-so-that-the-system-boots-in-text-mode) did not work. guiverc also points out that `text` as boot parameter only refers to outputting kernel messages as text, not to booting into a command line interface.

Comment: fyi: 'quiet' reduces the boot messages, 'splash' causes a graphic (splash screen) to be shown.  your use of 'text' only causes boot messages to scrolled in text on startup.  they have nothing to do with gdm/gui

Comment: "Rinzwind's systemctl command works for me, while the similar systemctl command from this previous question did not work" Similar? They're both `systemctl set-default multi-user.target`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabling the desktop from loading is a systemd setting

To (permanently) disable the desktop from commandline...

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

To (permanently) enable the desktop again from commandline...

```
systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

From the grub options you can also add to the boot options for a ONE time change (on reboot you either have to redo this or will get a desktop)...

```
systemd.unit=multi-user.target
```

Similar to (permanently) disabling gdm from commandline:

```
systemtcl disable gdm
```

(gdm can be changed to any other desktop name; kdm, xdm etc).

Comment: Your advice for disabling gdm has worked (and I learned about systemd). Thank you.
But after applying the command to restore the desktop I now get a unterminating loop  on boot. It keeps alternating between  showing the kernel log and trying to launch the graphics environment. Currently investigating.

Comment: Running `sudo service gdm3 start` from a tty results in the same loop, as the system tries to launch Gnome and fails, momentarily showing the tty

Comment: That gdm fails after reenabling seems to be a consequence of what I did when the `graphical.target` was disabled. Thanks for your help