# Install text mode Ubuntu

Tags: installation, unity, virtualization, text-mode

I have to run four OSs simultaneously and do not need graphical desktop. and I have only Ubuntu desktop CD.
Is it possible to install Ubuntu desktop without graphical environment?

Comment: also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-do-i-disable-x-at-boot-time-so-that-the-system-boots-in-text-mode

Answer (score 3):

You can install Ubuntu Server. There is no X-Server by default.

Comment: Excuse me, I meant graphical environment. the question has been edited.

Comment: The X-Server is the base of a gui in linux. No X-Server -> No GUI.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_server

Comment: But when you install Ubuntu, We have GUI by default, aren't us?

Comment: Not if you install Ubuntu Server:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server

Comment: Oh, cool. But I just have Ubuntu Desktop CD. I am going to edit to emphasis this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9307/discussion-between-mohammad-etemaddar-and-quidage)

Answer (score 2):

With the Desktop CD: No. As it seems to me, you have to do the normal desktop install and then remove the unneeded unity/gnome stuff.

Comment: Can you provide instructions on how to remove that stuff?

Comment: Install synaptic and search for gnome- unity and so so.