# How to revert back to GUI as the default interface from CLI in Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: boot, command-line, grub2, lightdm, gui

I was able to set up a text-only UI (CLI) by editing the file /etc/default/grub in Ubuntu 12.04 as per the instructions in:
[How do I disable X (GUI) at boot so that the system boots in CLI mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-do-i-disable-x-at-boot-time-so-that-the-system-boots-in-text-mode) using these commands:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

to open the *grub* file and replaced the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”
```

with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”text”
```

which sets CLI as default session.

---

But, how do I revert to X-session (GUI) as the default one? I don't want to log into text mode and 'start' the lightdm every time. So I tried replacing back the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`, and did `update-grub` too, but something unexpected happened, an unbootable system! (probably the DM got meshed up) How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution! So I'm posting it here myself...

To revert back to a graphical login and session (X session), `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"` in the /etc/default/grub file should be replaced by `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash reboot=bios"` (or `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash reboot=api"` for some Dell laptops). After having done this editing, save the file and run the `update-grub` command, and then `reboot` to see if the graphical login greeter appears. If it does, that's it... you can then log-in...

But if you still remain stuck with the problem *(like I was..)*, you can try using ***gdm*** as your *display-manager (DM)* or you could also try *reinstalling* ***lightgdm***. I uninstalled lightgdm and set gdm as the new manager with the command that follows:

```
sudo stop lightdm
sudo start gdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

and choose the DM you want so that it is set as the default option.

If your choice of DM was ***gdm***, now you may uninstall lightdm, `sudo apt-get remove lightdm`, and `sudo reboot`. And there you are with our old ***gdm*** graphical display-manager.

But if you choose ***lightdm*** which if which crashed earlier like mine did, you'd like to do a reinstall of lightdm instead like described below:

Log-in to a new tty (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>) and enter the commands;

```
sudo stop lightdm
sudo apt-get purge lightdm
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

and then set lightdm as the default manager and reboot to see it in effect.