# Login to command line

Tags: login, lightdm, console

It's possible to perform a login ( with `lightdm` or anything else ) and enter directly in command line mode without enabling any GUI for the user ?

Comment: @MadMike where I said that I want to disable something ? I just want to login right into a shell

Comment: "...without enabling any GUI for the user" sounds like you want to disable the GUI.

Comment: What do you mean by "without enabling any GUI for the user"? Whether the GUI is running or not isn't, generally speaking, user-specific. With the current level of detail and requirements presented in your question, [that](http://askubuntu.com/q/16371) does seem to answer it as well as it can be answered, especially since you didn't like [that answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/404528) which allows the GUI to be used but *does not require it at all.* If none of this helps, I recommend *editing* your question, detailing what you need. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console.

Answer (score 5):

You could just use a TTY without LightDM.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1 – F6</kbd> <sub>(Any key from <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd>)</sub>.
2. You can then enter your username and password to login. No symbols are shown for the password.
3. You will have a shell. Use `logout` to logout.
4. If you want to return to LightDM, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: this is trivial, and also defeats my main point: it still requires a login into a GUI; your "solution" is basically a switch back and forth

Comment: No, it doesn't... the user is just telling you how could you go back to a GUI if you wanted it...

Comment: @user2485710 A GUI is not required. "**If you want to**", LightDM is completely unnecessary.