# how to unity avoid in preseed file ubutu12.04

Tags: 12.04, unity, preseed

I wrote a preseed file for the Ubuntu 12.04 installation.

1. But I want to avoid the unity-desktop. Is there any way to do this?

   and another thing is
2. I tried to use cryptic password and generated by

   ```
   printf ubuntu | mkpasswd -s -m sha-512
   ```

The result is

```
$6$jZTXSnF0Gp$FawMAQXm2qfDzyKaknFs9NEU48s6z1Kxto6WI55Qf//tbeh4k//0IXS01yB.MA3Euk1ZLXb5lbq8y0j.JnEY9.
```

I pasted this in the preseed file. But after the installation, when I tried to login using the password `ubuntu` I can't login. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Avoid unity-desktop:

If you want to avoid unity desktop and rather have a CLI you'll have to edit the `/etc/default/grub` file. This link explains how:

- [How do I disable X at boot time so that the system boots in text mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-do-i-disable-x-at-boot-time-so-that-the-system-boots-in-text-mode)

#### Unable to login:

It's because you suppose the password to be "ubuntu", but its not... as,

```
printf ubuntu | mkpasswd -s -m sha-512
```

is not the correct way to specify the password to generate the hash.

You should do it this way:

```
echo "ubuntu" | mkpasswd -s -m sha-512
```

or simply:

```
mkpasswd -s -m sha-512
```

and then enter the password (ubuntu, as in your example).

Use the sha-512 hash thus generated.

Comment: i usually do network networkboot.so i dont want to download the desktop packages form my server.this'll make intallation fast (i generally use gnome shell).