# How can I get SD cards to mount automatically even when X isn’t running?

Tags: mount

I have an old laptop with a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04. The GUI is painfully slow, especially when something is animating, so I followed [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/79682/163358) to prevent the window manager from starting when my computer starts up.

When the window manager was running, if I plugged in my USB SD-card reader the card would be mounted automatically. This doesn’t happen when I’m in command-line mode. Is there a way to get Ubuntu to mount the card automatically even when the window manager isn’t running?

Comment: Does installing `usbmount` and then rebooting do it? I don't have an SD card reader on my CLI install so I can't test it. I know it works for USB drives though.

Comment: I would seriously recommend using a lighter version of linux such as lubuntu or dsl rather than running everything through a terminal, however that also sounds really cool

Comment: fluxbox is way lighter

Answer (score 1):

You will want to install and set up [udisks](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions#udisks).

They should then be accessible in `/mnt/media/`, named by their UUID.

You can see the UUID's of the currently-connected devices by running `sudo blkid` or `ls /dev/disk/by-uuid/`.

Comment: "udisk" alone do not mount disks, can you expand on how this can be archived?

Answer (score 1):

The process that listens for udisk events in GNOME is gvfsd(1). I think that if you start it in the background in a terminal session you should get automount.

Volumes mounted via gvfsd should be unmounted using gvfs-mount -u /media/volumename

Answer (score 1):

I use devmon running in a separate terminal. It is installed with the udevil package. the default mount location is /media/(Drive label).