# how do i prevent ubuntu from starting GUI automaticaly?

Tags: gui

i am looking for a way to start my GUI manually when ubuntu loads something like back-track which you login in first using command-line then type `startx` then GUI starts to running

Comment: It's something that depends strictly on hardware and drivers. Probably you have too see http://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed

Comment: @ValerioBozz How to not start X11 automatically does not depend on hardware and drivers, and also has nothing to do with controlling fan speed. Did you mean to post this on a different question?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable It by using

`sudo update-rc.d -f lightdm remove`

The above commmand will remove the lightdm symlinks in the various runlevel init directories e.g. /etc/rc0.d, rcS.d, rc2.d etc..

Now after every login you need to enter `startx` command mannually to start GUI.

To enble it type

`sudo update-rc.d -f lightdm defaults`

Comment: good! i will try, one more thing how can i enable it again?

Comment: Ok, I have added it.

Comment: it didn`t work :(

Comment: try this answer. http://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-do-i-disable-x-at-boot-time-so-that-the-system-boots-in-text-mode