# My laptop doesn't recognize its internal disk as bootable. How do I fix this?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I bought a [Toshiba Satellite](https://www.toshiba.com/us/computers/laptops/satellite/C50/C55-B5302) and installed Ubuntu using a [homemade liveusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Linux_Live_Usb_Creator), choosing to use the entire HDD and set up an encrypted LVM in the process. The installer finished with no errors, but the laptop's firmware didn't seem to recognize the HDD as bootable; powering it on without the flash drive gave me this error (capitalization not mine):

```
Reboot and select proper Boot device
or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key
```

I booted back to the liveusb, zeroed out the first few mebibytes of the HDD for good measure, and ran the installer again the same way, with the same result. After this, I tried `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` and `sudo update-grub` from the installed system. Both completed successfully, but didn't fix the problem.

Someone from Freenode/#ubuntu was kind enough to write a pair of GRUB commands that I could use at the flash drive's GRUB shell to boot from the HDD:

```
search --set=root --file /grub/grub.cfg
configfile /grub/grub.cfg
```

And a handy menu entry:

```
menuentry "Load Installed Ubuntu's grub.cfg" {
    search --set --fs-uuid $sda2_uuid
    configfile /grub/grub.cfg
}
```

(`$sda2_uuid` is the UUID of the partition that gets mapped to `/dev/sda2` and mounted at `/boot` in the installed system. `/dev/sda1` is mounted at `/boot/efi`.)

This works well enough as a temporary measure, though obviously it's impractical for the long term, as it requires me to keep the flash drive around.

What's going on here? How do I get this laptop to recognize its HDD as bootable?

---

### Partition table (`sudo parted /dev/sda print`)

```
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABF0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   794MB  256MB  ext2
 3      794MB   500GB  499GB
```

---

### Update

I remembered reading somewhere that the EFI partition (`/dev/sda1` in my case) should be FAT16, so I made a disk image of it, formatted it as FAT16, and copied all the files back. After rebooting, the an error would flash up an error for a split second:

```
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi
```

There was a `./EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` (relative to the root of `sda1`), so I copied it to `./EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` and the laptop now boots on its own. It still doesn't give me a GRUB menu, and now it also gets stuck on a solid purple screen for a good half minute before it shows any indication of getting on with the boot process (despite me having [replaced `quiet splash` in the kernel arguments with `text`](https://askubuntu.com/a/79682)), but it boots.

This seems like a rather crude solution, and I don't know *why* it worked in my case, so I won't post it as an answer. I'll keep messing with it, though; hopefully I'll find something better.

Answer (score 0):

***Great security comes with great responsibility.***

Your BIOS itself simply cannot boot from an encrypted partition. What you should have done is: create a small (unencrypted) boot partition that loads the LVM and the encryption/decryption module and hands over the boot process to the encrypted encryption/decryption module which then completes the boot process.

TrueCrypt is software that completely automates this, and its sole developer is not maintaining the software any more, but it's still be best out there!

So what you have to do now is:

1. Make an *unencrypted* backup of your date (if you have any)
2. Read the manual of the encryption software you're going to use completely (hopefully TrueCrypt) and use the LVM manuals to create your LVs (if this is your first time using LVM).
3. Re-install using the procedure above

Comment: I didn't do this by hand; I used the graphical installer and just ticked the boxes for encryption and LVM. The disk has three partitions and (to the best of my knowledge) is set up as you've said; I'll add the partition table to my answer in a couple minutes.