# How do I disable X after boot?

Tags: boot, gui, xserver

I was reading "[How do I disable X at boot time so that the system boots in text mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-do-i-disable-x-at-boot-time-so-that-the-system-boots-in-text-mode?newreg=afdad2ed6c5f4b2684113178c47a8bc9)" and will be implementing this. I see in the answer that there is a simple way to start the GUI but don't see how I would turn it back off after doing what I needed with out shutting down the computer. So how do I turn off X but keep the system running as normal and not shutting down?

Answer (score 1):

It depends *how* you start X after disabling it at boot time, I think.

If you invoke a display manager such as lightdm (i.e. `sudo service lightdm start`) then you will need to stop the service again (`sudo service lightdm stop`).

On the other hand, if you start a desktop session via xinit (i.e. using the `startx` command), then simply exiting from the session (using the desktop's `Log out...` function or a commandline equivalent such as `gnome-session-quit`) should return you to the CLI prompt.