# Installing Ubuntu on a sager like gaming laptop

Tags: nvidia, games

Smaller question version:

```
- How to boot Ubuntu Desktop into shell without X?
- Or how to install Ubuntu with default drivers, without nouveaux, bumblebee and nvidia* ?
```

Longer quest version with history:

Hello!
I need help with ubuntu instalation on my laptop.
I'm an avarage user. Had it installed on my desktop, played some games with Steam and playonlinux... 
But it was easy, because Ubuntu detected everything automaticaly. I installed on my parents notebook too, and it was smooth. 
They all had 3 or more years old hardware.

But my laptop requires skills beyond me, that I still do not possess.

The history with my laptop and ubuntu started with 14.04.
It booted from USB, worked for some time then freezed. I think it had something to do the touchpad. While I was using a mouse, the system seamed stable.
I could play some games with it too, but when I started any 3D GAME, my video card cooler whent max speed and didnt stop before a reboot.
My Wifi worked, but not so well.. Connection kept droping.

When 14.04.1 came, I tried once again. Same thing, and my wifi didnt work at all.

When 14.04.2 came, It wouldnt even boot. It got stuck at a nouveaux error. Booting with noacpi, it started X. But, when I made a click with the mouse, or touched the touchpad, it freezed.
Wifi, didnt work at all too.

-> About my notebook:
Its a sager equivalent Gaming PC.
It has a 4th Gen i7 mobile.
A GTX 780M Nvidia + Intel

What I did so far:

```
- About the touchpad: I red somewhere that Unity had some problems with some kinds of touchpads. I tried Xubuntu and Mint, and it ALMOST worked. X freezed in a much lower rate, and I could Ctrl + Alt + F2 to a shell, then Ctrl + Alt + F7 back to X, that it worked. With Unity, hole system freezed.
- About video-card: instaled xorg-edger drivers, updated kernel to the latest version, tried others distros. All distros based on kernel 3.16 or higher wouldnt even boot.
- About wifi: Installed WDCI, removing network-manager and network-manager-gnome, but it didnt work. I red some posts saying to increase the signal power, but I'm afraid of frying my network adapter, so i didn't do it.
```

-> A light at the end of the tunel:

Last week I had an idea. I created a real fisical disk with vmware pointing to a PenDrive with 32Gb.
I installed the new Elementary OS Freya in it, then apt-get update, upgrade and dist-upgrade.
Since VMWARE had no nvidia card, no bublebee, nvidia, nouveaux were installed by default.
With a clean system, I added xorg-edger ppa and installed the latest nvidia nvidia-prime.
When I booted my laptop using the USB stick, evertying worked! 
- Wifi could connect, and althoug much better, with still connection dropping, but in a smaller rate. (im using my smartfone thethering trough USB for a stable connection)
- Played some games from harddisk with playonlinux and video card cooler worked like a charm.
- Touchpad had no problem at all.

-> What I want:

I want to install Ubuntu. If Unity still have issues with touchpad, I dont mind installing Pantheon or XFCE later.
But, how do I do it? How can I make ubuntu install without nouveaux, nvidia drivers so I can boot into it? Could be even on shell without X. (i would need some help connecting wifi in shell)
About my wifi, when my sistem is up and running, I will look further into it.

I'm open to sugestions.
Tnks in advance, and sorry for the long post. If it was 9gag, I would post a Potato.

Comment: There is some key can be pressed during boot to bring up the GRUB menu. From there you can boot into the root shell.

Answer (score 0):

How can I make Ubuntu install without nouveaux and nvidia drivers?

My suggestion for this one is a very advanced one. You could make a custom ubuntu image that will allow you to remove packages you don't want, and add packages that you do. Including changing grub before you make your image so it won't boot into a graphical mode. Here's the link to a guide that walks you through it step by step. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

How can I can I boot Ubuntu without X?

You can use this guide [How do I disable X at boot time so that the system boots in text mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-do-i-disable-x-at-boot-time-so-that-the-system-boots-in-text-mode) to edit grub and boot without x at startup. However, this guide requires you to be logged into the system to make changes, so you may have to edit grub at boot. If you boot directly into grub, and pres 'e' (for edit) you should get some code displayed. If you look for the "quiet splash" line and manually change it to "text". Once you save and edit, you will boot into Ubuntu without an X.

It may be possible to boot into Ubuntu without graphics and remove the other packages you want rid of without starting x. This might be the simplest solution.