# How to start lightdm services at startup

Tags: boot, grub2, lightdm, systemd

My system is running Ubuntu 15.04 and I've changed  default boot to "`text`" instead of "`quiet splash`" by going through answer by @Bruno Pereira [How do I disable X at boot time so that the system boots in text mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-do-i-disable-x-at-boot-time-so-that-the-system-boots-in-text-mode).However again I've changed default boot to `quiet splash` and `update-grub` but as Ubuntu 15.04 uses `systemd` my system does not boot to graphical login and stuck at Ubuntu Logo screen.I've to go to the `tty1` terminal by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and manullay starts Lightdm services as `sudo service lightdm start` on every login.

How should I change my boot to Graphical login i.e "`quiet splash`"?
content of `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: have you tried update-grub2 ? I think it should back to default conf when you update it, no need to define lightdm on startup, also check your ubuntu-session.

Comment: Post the output of `sudo systemctl get-default`

Comment: And run `sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target`

Answer (score 5):

First run this command for a graphical environment

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

Because you have used `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target` before.

---

Then repair the entries in `/etc/default/grub`

This statement is completely wrong:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Open the configuration:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and replace the entry

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

with

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

add the entry

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash"
```

After that run

```
sudo update-grub
```

---

- GRUB_DEFAULT

  The default menu entry. This may be a number, in which case it identifies the Nth entry in the generated menu counted from zero, or the title of a menu entry, or the special string ‘saved’. Using the title may be useful if you want to set a menu entry as the default even though there may be a variable number of entries before it.
- GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX

  Command-line arguments to add to menu entries for the Linux kernel.
- GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT

  Unless ‘GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY’ is set to ‘true’, two menu entries will be generated for each Linux kernel: one default entry and one entry for recovery mode. This option lists command-line arguments to add only to the default menu entry, after those listed in ‘GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX’.

<sub>[Source](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Simple-configuration.html)</sub>

Comment: It is not working

Comment: without `quiet splash` it is booting in to command-line

Comment: Therefore `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Comment: That seems to be an other problem.

Comment: Try a `sudo apt-get install --reinstall`

Comment: @A.B. I think the problem with `sudo systemctl enable multi-user.target --force; sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target` see Bruno's answer. OP has 15.04 with `systemd`. There should be a command to reverse that.

Comment: @Sneetsher this is a good point.

Comment: @A.B. after running  `sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target` and grub changes and `update-grub` i am able to boot in to GUI but not able to drop any terminal  `tty1`to `tty6` and boot process is not default Ubuntu logo boot but from `text`to`login-screen`

Comment: @A.B. yes when i set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash"` it is booting normally instead of replacing

Comment: @A.B. after some failed kernel module it boots normally

Comment: @A.B. however it is some workaround and not a solution so upvoted it but not accepted thanks for your effort

Comment: Try a `sudo systemctl enable serial-getty@.service`

Comment: @A.B. Tried `sudo systemctl enable serial-getty@.service`

Answer (score 2):

It depends on why it doesn't start as a default option. I accidentally purge systemd, so when I reinstall and boot I just have the TTY prompt.

First, you haver to start the service so you can do it graphical:

```
sudo start lightdm
```

Once you are in gui mode type in the terminal to reconfigure lightdm:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm

sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

Now we need to update the grub so lightdm start a default service

```
init=/lib/systemd/systemd
```

To boot under systemd by default, edit /etc/default/grub and change the following line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash init=/lib/systemd/systemd"
```

After modifying any grub related configuration files like /etc/default/grub the following command is needed to bring the changes into effect.

```
update-grub
```

You can see all the instructions in the official ubuntu wiki [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/systemd), systemd is a services administrator so you will find quite functional