# Cinnamon install broken in 17.04. Black background, icons not changing

Tags: themes, cinnamon, icon-themes

I did a clean install of Ubuntu Gnome today.  I installed cinnamon and switched to it  (I left gnome installed). I was customizing the theme, and all settings were taking effect immediately, but I can't change the icon theme.  Even if I select a theme and logout and back in nothing changes. Also, if I close the theme window and reopen it, it still has the icon theme that I chose, but it has the icon from the default Adwaita displayed.  I ran updates and restarted, and now there is no desktop background and the ctrl-alt-T shortcut for terminal isn't working.  I have tried reinstalling cinnamon, and nothing changed. I am running Cinnamon 3.2.7 on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04.

tldr;

When I select a theme for icon in cinnamon nothing happens.  I can change all of the other theme settings.  After a reboot the desktop is black and some keyboard shortcuts don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after much experimentation I found a workaround, and a more permanent solution.

### The Workaround

There were multiple issues, with separate solutions.

To solve the issue of the background being dark, I had to switch from the gnome greeter to lightdm:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

...and then select lightdm.  Now Cinnamon used the background from the greeter, which could be changed with the lightdm GTK+ greeter settings tool.  This is not ideal, but it works.

To change the icon theme, I had to use the gnome tweak tool.  I don't know why, but that correctly changed the icon theme.

As for the default keyboard shortcuts, I had to add them again. Instead of using the built in 'launch terminal' shortcut, I had to make a custom shortcut that ran `gnome-terminal`. Not ideal, but it works.

### The Longer-Term Solution

I still don't know exactly which programs were causing these issues, but I figured that the cleaner the install I could do the better.

I reinstalled, this time with the [minimal ubuntu installer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD). After that, I installed cinnamon, and enabled lightdm, using instructions from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624816/how-to-start-lightdm-services-at-startup).

```
sudo apt-get install cinnamon-desktop-environment
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

in `/etc/default/grub` change the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash init=/lib/systemd/systemd"
```

and finally run

```
sudo update-grub
```

This gave me a working cinnamon install on Ubuntu.
To get a nicer and more configurable greeter, I also installed the lightdm GTK+ greeter, and settings tool.

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm-gtk-greeter lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings
```