# Ubuntu 15.04 remastering boot option "text"

Tags: boot, remastersys, text-mode

I remastered an Ubuntu 14.04 ISO. In isolinux.cfg I could use the boot-option "text". Remastering 15.04 this no longer works. "text" mode is ignored and the gui/desktop starts. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the a similar problem just now, updating from 14.04 to 15.04. The answer here helped me:
https://askubuntu.com/a/79682/427786

Specifically these commands:

```
sudo systemctl enable multi-user.target --force
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```