# Using grub2 for temporary boot into text mode

Tags: boot, grub2, 15.04, systemd, text-mode

I want to boot temporary into text mode using grub2 and followed the steps explained in [How to boot into command line on Ubuntu or Debian](http://ask.xmodulo.com/boot-into-command-line-ubuntu-debian.html). Running `cat /proc/cmdline` from the terminal than gives the following output:

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-30-generic root=UUID=65462cb0-1e5e-438a-a8d8-4d93877cc7ca ro text vt.handoff=7
```

From which I understand that the kernel parameter 'text' was interpreted. However the system still boots with display manager.

I suspect this is caused by systemd bypassing whatever has interpreted the 'text' argument. Hence my question: how can I temporary start the system in text mode from grub2 at boot?

Comment: Suspicion correct! [Does this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/79682/527764) work?