# 15.10: 'startx $(which unity)' fails when booting to console

Tags: boot, unity, xorg

I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/79682/367990) and ran the following commands on my 15.10 with Unity Desktop to boot to text mode:

```
sudo systemctl enable multi-user.target --force
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

The first command gave me the following output though, but I proceeded anyway:

```
The unit files have no [Install] section. They are not meant to be enabled
using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.
3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
```

I also modified the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"` line in in `/etc/default/grub` and ran `sudo update-grub` afterwards.

---

The system then booted successfully into text mode and I could use the TTY1 login mask. But after that, I wanted to start the desktop using `startx $(which unity)`, which failed with the error message below (white text on red background btw.):

```
X.Org X Server 1.17.2
Release Date: 2015-06-16
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.13.0-68-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux ecs-harigel-webserver 4.2.0-27-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 04:49:08 UTC 2016 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic root=UUID=17983985-9c67-4e5b-a6fd-0c501c5abc41 ro text
Build Date: 12 November 2015  05:33:29PM
xorg-server 2:1.17.2-1ubuntu9.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Feb  3 10:28:57 2016
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but <RALT> has 2 symbols
>                   Ignoring extra symbols
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/unity", line 21, in <module>
    import glib
ImportError: No module named glib
xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

The commands `startx /usr/bin/gnome-session --session=ubuntu` and plain `startx` bring me to a broken desktop consisting of only the wallpaper and an X-shaped cursor which only moves on the diagonal line from the top left corner downwards to the right..

If it helps, here's the output of `env`:

```
XDG_VTNR=1
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
XDG_SESSION_ID=c1
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=linux
HUSHLOGIN=FALSE
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
USER=bytecommander
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
MAIL=/var/mail/bytecommander
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
PWD=/home/bytecommander
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
XDG_SEAT=seat0
HOME=/home/bytecommander
LOGNAME=bytecommander
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
_=/usr/bin/env
```

`which python` reports `/usr/bin/python`, which is version 2.7.10.

Looking at python's `sys.path` value, it's the same booting to text mode and booting to desktop, but compared to another 15.10 installation, the value `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0` is missing here. I can't import `glib` in python neither when booted to text mode nor in desktop mode. On the other 15.10 machine, that works.

The package `python-dbus` is installed in version `1.2.0-2build3` on both systems (the one which makes problems and the one I compare it to).

Why did this happen and how can I fix it to be able to start the GUI when booted into text mode?

Comment: What if you run `startx gnome-session --session=ubuntu`? (or `unity`, I don't remember what the session is called, exactly)

Comment: @muru It does not recognize the `--session=unity` option as it seems. I added the output to my question. Same for `--session=ubuntu`.

Comment: The first way was correct, but the full path to `gnome-session` needs to be used: `startx /usr/bin/gnome-session --session=ubuntu`. Without that it started xterm, which of course doesn't understand `--session=ubuntu`.

Comment: @muru That did the same as plain `startx` and left me with only the wallpaper, and an X-shaped mouse cursor which could only move on the diagonal from the top-left corner downwards to the right. Unusable.

Comment: @muru Added more information to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the package `python-gtk2` was missing. I installed it:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gtk2
```

That explains the difference in Python's `sys.path` (`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0` was missing). But on the other machine where the entry was present, according to `aptitude why`, the package was only installed as dependency of `compizconfig-settings-manager`, an obviously optional package. I think this package should be converted into a dependency of Unity instead!

But the Unity Desktop I get is still not usable. It has a screen resolution of 800x600 and all indicators are missing, the panel is completely empty. Also I can't change the settings (e.g. the display resolution), which results in an error like this:

[image: screenshot: Failed to apply configuration]

I'm opening a new question on this:
[Unity Desktop incomplete when launching manually using 'startx $(which unity)'](https://askubuntu.com/q/729196/367990)