# Unity Desktop incomplete when launching manually using 'startx $(which unity)'

Tags: unity, xorg, dbus, gnome-settings-daemon

This is a follow-up question to [15.10: 'startx $(which unity)' fails when booting to console](https://askubuntu.com/q/729130/367990).

I finally managed to load the Unity Desktop after having booted into text-mode. But the desktop I get is still not usable. It has a screen resolution of 800x600 and all indicators are missing, the panel is completely empty. Also I can't change the settings (e.g. the display resolution), which results in an error like this:

[image: screenshot: Failed to apply configuration]

What is happening here? When I boot directly into the graphical desktop environment, there are zero problems. What am I missing when booting to console and starting the desktop manually?

I currently do that by executing `startx $(which unity)`.

Please help me to be able to successfully start the Unity desktop manually from a pure console.

Comment: As before, how about `startx /usr/bin/gnome-session --session=ubuntu`?

Comment: @muru Nope. As before, I get the absolutely unusable wallpaper plus X-shaped mouse cursor which only moves on a diagonal line.

Comment: It's not recommended to use startx in Ubuntu.

Comment: @xangua It does not help when you tell me that I should not do it that way without providing a better alternative...

Comment: @ByteCommander That is very unusual. What does `grep Exec /usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop` say? That's the command that actually launches the unity session, so if it still doesn't work, I'd think something very wrong

Comment: @muru Output: `Exec=gnome-session --session=ubuntu`, `TryExec=unity`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could follow the chain of targets from the point you stopped at and manually load the graphical target as if you didn't stop at the multi-user target at all:

```
sudo systemctl start graphical.target
```

That will handle everything correctly.

But bear in mind that this will start LightDM, which will in turn start Unity upon login, and not Unity directly.

---

To leave the graphical desktop again in favor of the console, load the multi-user.target:

```
sudo chvt 1 && sudo systemctl start multi-user.target
```

The `sudo chvt 1` additionally switches back from TTY7 (GUI) to TTY1 (console), because otherwise you would stay on a black screen.

Comment: I added how to leave the desktop again. Thanks! :)

Comment: @ByteCommander Huh, it took me less than 5 minutes to forget about that. -.-

Comment: I'm not too sure I understand your answer. Are you saying that you cannot use startx anymore? Instead you switch between the `multi-user` and the `graphical` targets?