# No graphical interface after editing /etc/default/grub

Tags: boot, grub2, 18.04

After some research in the try of solving a problem with sound in Ubuntu 18.04, I found some answers involving editing of the file `/etc/default/grub`. After playing with this file and rebooting, surprisingly, Ubuntu booted in terminal mode instead of graphical.

Then, I did some search on how to get back to GUI from CLI, but every solution I found just didn't work (I tried `startx` command so as to start GUI, but it holds for some time and then times out saying "time out in locking authority file").

Also I tried `init 5` but this also shows GUI for a blink of an eye and then gets back into the terminal. I tried the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> combination, but it appears that it does nothing.

I tried to reinstall `ubuntu-desktop`, but it faced broken packaged and failed to do so; afterward I got to know that `aptitude` could possibly solve this issue automatically, but it didn't.

I'm new to Ubuntu and any measure I take at this step seem to worsen the situation!! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What changes did you make to /etc/default/grub?  Did you run `sudo update-grub` afterwards?

Comment: As Charles suggested, it would be helpful to know what changes you made to /etc/default/grub. Also, you may want to have a look at this: https://askubuntu.com/a/729211/787506. As for fixing broken packages, see this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1028516/787506

Comment: To be exact I added some numbers before "quiet splash" phrase at GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and yes I  did update-grub command .but as soon as I realized that the cause of the problem is this I reverted the file to its initial state but the problem didn't solve.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your `/etc/default/grub`, do:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Remove everything and add these (default Ubuntu grub file instructions excluding comments):

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Save using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Then do:

```
sudo update-grub
```