# Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox and access to comman line

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, windows-7

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 to VirtualBox in Windows 7.
Is it possible to access only to command line for code compilation purposes and then edit same code in Windows?
Sorry that my question is related to Windows, but I don't know any other place to ask. I would rather install ubuntu to whole laptop, but I just now can't.

Answer (score 0):

You could use server version of the OS - that comes with no GUI whatsoever. If you insist on using Desktop version, your question requires combination of two things.

First , if you need to edit same file in both Windows and Ubuntu VM, you need to have a shared folder between virtual machine and the host OS. With VirtualBox, you will need to set that up in Settings -> Shared Folders.

[image]
In addition to that, I suggest you add your user on virtual machine to `vboxsf` group. Use `sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf username` for that

Second, you need to [disable X server](https://askubuntu.com/q/16371/295286) (the GUI) in the VM. Basically, you need to alter `/etc/default/grub` file to have `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"`