# Run Terminal commands on boot Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, command-line

I want to have my system boot into CLI only (no X, GUI) and run some sudo (root) commands.

An example would be Terminal launch on boot and run `sudo cd Desktop/folder` then `sudo ./Example -c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address booting into the command line,

> Edit `/etc/default/grub` with your favourite editor, e.g. `nano`:
>
> ```bash
> sudo nano /etc/default/grub
> ```
>
> Find this line:
>
> ```bash
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
> ```
>
> Change it to:
>
> ```bash
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
> ```
>
> Update GRUB:
>
> ```bash
> sudo update-grub
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **For systems that use systemd**, (This is an additional step for systemd releases, e.g. Ubuntu 15.04), **the steps above for grub are still necessary.**
>
> You need to tell `systemd` to not load the graphical login manager:
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl enable multi-user.target --force
> sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
> ```
>
> You will still be able to use X by typing `startx` after you logged
>   in.

## *Please note that all credit is due to the original author [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-do-i-disable-x-at-boot-time-so-that-the-system-boots-in-text-mode).*

---

Regarding running a command on startup:

All you have to do is add the command to the end of your `/etc/rc.local` file.

For example, you would add

```bash
sudo "/home/yourUserHere/Desktop/folder/Example.sh"
```

Comment: I still had to execute `systemctl` commands to disable the GUI on 16.04. Maybe because my ubuntu was upgraded from 15.04?