# How do I enable X at boot time so that the system boots not in text mode?

Tags: boot, lightdm, xserver

[What I have made to disable X at boot time according to "marked as correct answer"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-do-i-disable-x-at-boot-time-so-that-the-system-boots-in-text-mode?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I have disabled X server on my machine (16.04), but now I want to do a roll back to old settings. I dont want to start lightdm service in every login. Can you help me to automize it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you at least summarized the steps you took to disable it - since the question you linked to has 23 different answers. Also please include the flavor and version of Ubuntu that you are running.

Comment: I update my question. Thank you for informing me.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to restore the default Ubuntu 16.10 settings after applying the commands from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/79682/413683) (`sudo systemctl enable multi-user.target --force` and `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target`).

The solution is to run:

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

I was able to deduce it from running `systemctl get-default` on an unmodified Ubuntu.