# Disable/change console login prompt

Tags: 16.04, login, systemd, tty, console

I want to have an application that will display slideshow with pictures user uploads to the samba share. My application is up and running but when I boot the system for a couple of seconds (before my application start) I can see a login screen that says:

```
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS slides-desktop tty1
slides-desktop login:
```

What I want to accomplish is to disable this prompt (and possibility to login via tty1) and replace it with sth else like "Welcome to the slide show!".
How can I achieve that?

I have disabled booting to X by following [this instruction](https://askubuntu.com/a/79682/476708).

**EDIT: 2016-10-17**

Any follow up on this?
I think that this is administered by systemd but I cannot find a proper file to change this.