# Xubuntu XFCE 4.12 issue

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

After restarting Xubuntu my desktop is changed. Keyboard won't work, top bar in windows missing, no background, desktop icons missing.

I deleted .config/xfce4 and issue remained.

If I hit Ctrl Alt F1, log-in, and startx everything works like before.

But if I restart my laptop the issue remains.

What could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: If you can't fix it, you may want to just boot directly to TTY1 since you mention all works fine by running the `startx` command. http://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-do-i-disable-x-at-boot-time-so-that-the-system-boots-in-text-mode#answer-79682

Comment: Got it.

It works fine but if I hit lock screen afterwards the screen became blank and I need to log in to tty2 to continue work.

Thanks