# Booting into text mode in 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, text-mode

Is there any way to temporarily disable GUI (X server) when booting an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installation?

There are various guides advising to add `text` option onto the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` or directly on the `linux` line in GRUB. These methods work well in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS but I always end up in LightDM when trying them in 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Much later found a related question: https://askubuntu.com/q/16371/250300

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To boot Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop without X one time, add `systemd.unit=multi-user.target` to the `linux` command line in GRUB.

To make this the default, use

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

To return to default booting into X, use

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

To see the current default target,

```
sudo systemctl get-default
```

Comment: Yes, this one works! However, I am pretty sure I won’t remember this method as easily as the old one…

Comment: @Melebius: How to remember: Ubuntu now uses systemd as the init system. Systemd has a notion of _target_ units, some of which correspond to the old-school bootlevels. When booting, systemd has the goal to achieve `default.target`, which can be symlinked to one of two: `multi-user.target` (system fully up, no graphics) and `graphical.target` (system fully up, with graphics).

Comment: For those who don't know how to edit GRUB command: press `Shift` during boot, and press `e` to edit selected boot command.

Comment: Thanks for your instruction, in my case I have to modify grub configuration as well.

`sudo vi /etc/default/grub`

Comment out `GRUB_CMD_LINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line by adding prefix `#`, modify `GRUB_CMD_LINE_LINUX` to `"text"`, and uncomment `GRUB_TERMINAL=console`. Then save and `sudo update-grub`

Comment: @longbkit That’s the _old_ option (without `systemd`) that I mentioned in the question.