# Is LibreOffice Calc available in Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS?

Tags: server, libreoffice

I am currently using Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS. Where I work with mainly LibreOffice Calc. But I have to work with a server as well, and I only have one PC. So if I install Ubuntu Server, can I use LibreOffice Calc as well?

Please try to answer as yes or no: Is LibreOffice Calc is preinstalled in ubuntu server or have I to manually install it?

Comment: Ubuntu Server does not come with a GUI (a server is more efficient without one), so you'll be *pretty-much* converting Ubuntu Server 18.04 into a desktop by installing the desktop & required deps to run LibreOffice Calc.  Ubuntu Desktop can run server functions too, so why?

Comment: "Ubuntu Desktop and Server are essentially the same distribution, just with different default package selection" - so yes. ([via](https://askubuntu.com/a/31144/631600))

Comment: @RoVo  You are saying that LibreOffice Calc is not pre installed in Ubuntu Server? You mean That i have to manually install it. Right?

Comment: Exactly. But to be able to use it you also need to install a desktop environment. Based on your questions **I very much doubt that Ubuntu Server is what you want**.

Comment: Note that you can also install server packages to your current Desktop edition.

Comment: Yes , I want Ubuntu server - with LibreOffice Calc.

Comment: @Melebius how can I install server packages?

Comment: `sudo apt install <package>` or use docker ... But please, the comment section is not for extended discussions, and in general askubuntu is not your tutor. This site is for specific questions about specific issues.

Comment: As [RoVo mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071885/is-libreoffice-calc-is-available-in-ubuntu-server-18-04-lts#comment1758646_1071890), this looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). For what purpose would you use the Ubuntu Server? Isn’t virtualization also an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

Usually in Ubuntu Server (and any other server distribution) there isn't the desktop manager (Gnome, KDE, ...). There isn't graphical environment.

But, anyway, you can install it and, obviously you also can install Libreoffice.

To install Gnome:

```
sudo tasksel ubuntu-desktop
```

If you want to install another desktop manager (Mate, XFCE, ...) you can follow this guide: https://linuxconfig.org/install-gui-on-ubuntu-server-18-04-bionic-beaver

Comment: Is there any way to install all packages of Ubuntu server in Ubuntu Desktop? like sudo-apt-get-install ubuntu-server?

Comment: yes, you can install server package in Ubuntu desktop. But are you sure you need a server? You need a server to give a service, for example a web server so you have to install apache or nginx, or a mail server so you have to install postifix, dovecot and others packages. Why you think you need a server?

Comment: Your question is a perfect example for an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please open a new question with your **specific** problem --> what do you want to achieve (not "I need to install a server"). Also do not ask "I want to do this and that", rather "I'm doing this and that and I am stuck at this certain point."

Answer (score 0):

To keep your server efficient, you start it in text mode, and run it in text mode when you need no program with a graphical user interface.

But when you want to run LibreOffice or some other graphical program, you start a graphical window manager with **`startx`** instead of installing a full desktop environment. This is described in the following link and links from it,

[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - how is the X server started?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/937097/ubuntu-16-04-lts-how-is-the-x-server-started/987945#987945)

In your case you want to install not only the basic program packages, but also libreoffice and maybe some other program packages too.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install fluxbox xinit xterm libreoffice
```