# Is there any GUI with terminals only?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, gui, window-manager, tiling

I’m using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver). Is there any graphical interface with terminals only? I wanted to use `terminator` to split the screen into 4 terminals, but I don’t need any other things, that graphical interface has (like internet browser, text editors and else programs).

Comment: I think your looking for a window manager. Check out things like `dwm` or `awesome` or maybe `xmonad` Edit: I've never actually tried a window manager on ubuntu though so ymmv...

Comment: I’d add [i3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I3_(window_manager)) to the list by @j-money. However, I also do not use any of these…

Comment: Thanks @Melebius Also FWIW I use dwm (on arch at the moment) for my daily driver and it works great, its lightweight and configuration is pretty simple if your're familaiar with C

Comment: Try `tilix` (terminal emulator), it has built-in tiling.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to reduce, disk space or ram? Tried just using a regular Ubuntu 18.04 (even running live from a USB), and remove all the packages you don't need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you want a minimal system in BIOS mode, start from an Ubuntu [`mini.iso`](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13211730#post13211730) file and install only what you want.
- If you want a minimal system in UEFI mode, start from a 64-bit [Ubuntu Server](http://releases.ubuntu.com/bionic/) iso file and and install only what you want (avoid server specific packages, that you don't need).
- There are many window managers. I have used Fluxbox. See also [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/937097/ubuntu-16-04-lts-how-is-the-x-server-started/987945#987945) that shows that it might be enough to install `fluxbox xinit xterm`. I think you will replace `xterm` with `terminator` and maybe `fluxbox` with some other window manager.