# Ubuntu 22.04 is crashing on Startup / Reboot

Tags: boot, network-manager, suspend, startup, crash

```
systemd[1]: Finished Download data for packages that failed at package install time.
dbus-daemon[886]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.timedate1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.timedate1.service' requested by ':1.72' (uid=0 pid=899 comm="/usr/lib/snapd/snapd " label="unconfined")
systemd[1]: Starting Time & Date Service...
dbus-daemon[886]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.timedate1'
systemd[1]: Started Time & Date Service.
systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: Deactivated successfully.
snapd[899]: devicemgr.go:2000: no NTP sync after 10m0s, trying auto-refresh anyway
snapd[899]: autorefresh.go:529: Cannot prepare auto-refresh change due to a permanent network error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
snapd[899]: stateengine.go:149: state ensure error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
systemd[1]: Started Session 5 of User root.
systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service: Deactivated successfully.
systemd[1]: Finished Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
NetworkManager[887]: <info>  [1665609482.8855] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
ModemManager[925]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is about to suspend
NetworkManager[887]: <info>  [1665609482.8857] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
gnome-shell[1390]: Screen lock is locked down, not locking
systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
systemd-sleep[2396]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
kernel: [ 1228.751330] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Deactivated successfully.
systemd[1]: Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
kernel: [ 1228.760746] Filesystems sync: 0.009 seconds
systemd[1]: grub-initrd-fallback.service: Deactivated successfully.
systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
```

Logs on other Ubuntu Machine
//--------------------------------------

```
 21:09:02  snapd[903]: devicemgr.go:2000: no NTP sync after 10m0s, trying auto-refresh anyway
 21:09:19  systemd[1]: Started Session 4 of User root.
 21:09:32  snapd[903]: autorefresh.go:529: Cannot prepare auto-refresh change due to a permanent network error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
 21:09:32  snapd[903]: stateengine.go:149: state ensure error: persistent network error: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
 21:11:19  systemd[1]: session-4.scope: Deactivated successfully.
 21:13:01  systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
 21:13:01  systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service: Deactivated successfully.
 21:13:01  systemd[1]: Finished Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
 21:17:01  CRON[2269]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Comment: It looks like your machine is entering suspend state on boot - this is very odd.

Comment: Looks like a fresh install is in order. Where there any errors on install or anything unusual.

Comment: Can you boot in recovery-mode? Or can you add in grubmenu `systemd.unit=multi-user.target`  https://askubuntu.com/questions/870221/booting-into-text-mode-in-16-04