# On a system that boots in text mode, how can I go back to CLI-only mode after starting the display manager?

Tags: command-line, xorg, login, lightdm, gui

I've set up Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS to boot in CLI mode, and to start a GUI I run `sudo lightdm start` in tty1.

My question is, Is there any way to quit GUI completely and get back to CLI in GUI?

I can quit GUI by `sudo lightdm stop` in tty2 (since tty1 is running lightdm and I can't insert any command) or simply by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. But it feels like an unusual way to me. And am I doing right to quit GUI?

Comment: You want to start your Ubuntu as a "server" i.e. without any GUI at all, is that right?

Comment: sudo lightdm (start|stop) , no need to go to tty2 to start / stop. If you have a problem with startx , post the error message. FWIW on servers consider a web administration tool.

Comment: [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-do-i-disable-x-at-boot-time-so-that-the-system-boots-in-text-mode) they tell you to boot in text mode.

Comment: For systemd-based systems, the preferred methods would probably be `sudo systemctl isolate multi-user.target` - and `sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target` instead of `sudo lightdm start` - these should be independent of the particular desktop manager.