# How to boot into runlevel 3 (as default) on Ubuntu Bionic(18.04)?

Tags: 18.04

What are the settings/commands to be made for Ubuntu Bionic so that it boots into runlvel 3 by default?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-do-i-disable-x-at-boot-time-so-that-the-system-boots-in-text-mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following command:

```
systemctl set-default runlevel3.target
```

Inspired by: [Post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373195/how-to-set-the-default-startup-level-on-ubuntu-16-4?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Comment: This answer worked first time for me on Bionic, many thanks. But don't forget the escalation, i.e. sudo systemctl set-default runlevel3.target

Comment: @TemporaryChicken then please accept as the answer